# catkin src/* vcs update

Tags: ros, catkin, packages, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I'm probably missing something here...

Is there/What is the equivalent of rosbuild's `rosws update` for catkin
in the sense of updating all repository checkouts in the source folder simultaneously?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62022/catkin-src/*-vcs-update/) by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2950 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `wstool` with catkin workspaces.

Use `rosws` with rosbuild workspaces.

The two types of workspaces and tools are completely orthogonal.

The equivalent to `rosws update` is `wstool -t path/to/src update`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2013-05-02**:
Ah, thank you for the quick answer.
Seems like I overlooked it here [http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying].